# Testing for client validations in Rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, jasmine

In the Rails application that I am working on I have a page that should display an error message when a field is not populated and the form is submitted.

The client side validation on the field is done using jQuery and it works fine from the browser , when I test it manually

The form is stopped from being submitted at all when data for a field is not entered by the user.

What are my options to write a test for this

1. I looked at Jasmine, but it seems to be more useful when i want to test the javascript function itself , not helpful to test if the event is firing correctly on the page.( let me know if i am wrong on this)
2. I looked at rspec and wrote a test like this

   ```
   require 'spec_helper'
   describe 'Sample Test Page' do      

      it 'should show error when Some Field is not specified' do
        visit  '/sample_page'
        click_button "Submit"  
        page.should have_content 'You forgot to Enter details in Some Field'
     end 
   end
   ```

but what is happening here is that the form gets submitted without the validation firing at all and I get an error ( since the application throws an error for blank value)

What is my best option ? Is there another tools that will help me test this in the Rails philosophy ?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to test JavaScript in integration tests, you need to explicitly specify it to pick a web driver supporting JavaScript.

In your case you used Webrat, it is fast but does not support JS, so your test failed.

The default web driver for Javascript is Selenium. To enable it, just change this line

```
describe 'Sample Test Page' do
```

To

```
describe 'Sample Test Page', js: true do
```

Then all tests under this block will run on Selenium. You'll see a real browser pop up to run your test.